# Sublime text: unexpected sidebar git marks behaviour

Tags: sublimetext, sidebar, sublimetext4

I'm using the most recent stable 4143 build on Ubuntu 22.04. Here's an image to show what I mean:

[image: Sidebar marks]

Looks great, right? Despite one fact: all that files were created and are not added to git index yet. Looks quite inconsistent: some files have empty circle (I'll call it a mark, because I don't know the proper term for it) and some do not.

First I thought that this is related to the way of file creation: initially all files created from terminal (via `touch` or `echo something > file` - it's often faster than going through new file procedure in ST, since I always have terminal open) had the sign, and everything created within ST did not. But this does not hold true and looks like a coincidence, because after a few attempts I created a file with the sign within ST.

This is also not 100% reproducible: sometimes it happens every time, and sometimes everything works fine. The signs can appear and disappear randomly (like after creation of a new file the sign disappears from the older one).

There are no error messages in ST console, and git integration works smoothly in other aspects.

The 2nd screenshot shows 4 files created with "New file" one-by-one in the same folder, created with `mkdir`. First three files had the mark in place, then after addition of the fourth one has lost the sign.

[image: Artificial reproduction]

Comment: this seems like a known bug which we'll have to wait for a fix in a future build https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5659

Comment: @KeithHall thank you! Could you post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Based on the linked issue, it's not even related to using Git, it occurs at all times.

Comment: @torek don't really understand your point, the linked issue discusses only git-related marks, here's why I added [tag:git] tag.

Comment: Ah - I skimmed too fast, I saw someone reply "no" to what I thought was a question about whether they were using Git. But the problem is entirely in sublime itself, not in Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug which we'll have to wait for a fix in a future build: https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/5659